# How to set the number of lines for a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am currently working on a project where I need to be able to set the number of lines for a UILabel. This means that if I input 5, the label has to conform and return 4 times (issues like having too few characters will not be a problem). Below I have attached an image containing an example of what I mean as to clarify my question:

[image]

So far, I have tried to do this by setting the .numberOfRows property, but this only places a limit on the UILabel which is not what I desire (if you are curious, there is some code below). Any help?

My code:

```
if Double(w!) > 277 {
    print("Values:")
    print(w!)
    let numRows = Int(w!/237)
    print(numRows)
    heightOfCell += Double(numRows)*20.5
    cell!.textLabel?.numberOfLines = numRows + 2
}
```

Comment: Unclear what "the label HAS to conform and return 4 times" means, so it is unclear what the goal is. Could you post some screen shots or something, to clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @matt I have edited my question, would you mind taking a second look?

Comment: Well in your illustrations this seems to have much more to do with changing the width at which the text wraps. Which could be the width of the label itself. Or it could be the preferredMaxLayoutWidth.

Comment: @BobSamuels are you trying to say that even after setting the property `numberOfLines`, your label still displays just one line ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to force the label to lay out in such a way that it ends up with the given number of lines. This cannot easily be done by the UILabel's standard interface. The normal behavior of a `UILabel` is to fill up the lines until it has reached the label's width, then add a new line for the remainder for the text, fill that line again and add additional lines as required until `numberOfLines` is reached. You should look for a ready to use custom label implementation somewhere in the open source community or come up with a custom solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For add more lines in the label,you can open the property of label and in the label property you can show lines option,in this option you can add the many more lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
Keep in mind that the .numberOfRows property will only set a limit to the number of lines your label can display. You will also have to divide your text into lines.

```
    class NumberOfLinesLabel:UILabel{

    func setNumberOfLines(n:Int){
        self.numberOfLines = n
        let words = self.text?.split(separator: " ")
        let numOfWordsPerLine = (words?.count)!/n
        var insertedWords = 0
        self.text = ""
        for w in words!{
            if insertedWords == numOfWordsPerLine{
                self.text = self.text! + "\n" + w
                insertedWords = 0
            }else if self.text?.count == 0{
                self.text = self.text! + w
                insertedWords += 1
            }else {
                self.text = self.text! + " " + w
                insertedWords += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```